# Rails scopes downcase before searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a scope to search the model in a case insensitive way.

```
scope :services_offered, -> (service) { joins(:my_services).where(my_services: {services: service.downcase }) }
```

I can downcase the argument passed to the scope but I'm stuck on how to now ignore case on the model.

Also Happy for suggestion of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable way would be to downcase the column inside the database via a bit of SQL:

```
scope :services_offered, -> (service) { joins(:my_services).where('lower(my_services.services) = ?', service.downcase) }
```

or:

```
scope :services_offered, -> (service) { joins(:my_services).where('lower(my_services.services) = lower(?)', service) }
```

Comment: Thats done it! Would that be considered the best way of doing this?

Comment: I'd probably lean towards the second one. `String#downcase` only knows about ASCII (until Ruby3 AFAIK) so you could run into strange issues if Ruby and your database aren't using exactly the same downcasing algorithm. Unlikely but...